# Python Regex - Positive Lookbehind Quantifier Alternative

Tags: python, regex

I have this dialog of a play by Shakespeare,What I want to do basically:

insert a colon (:) after every actor name. Thus the dialog becomes like this:

**BRUTUS: Bla blah blah**

**CESAR: Bla blah blah**

**ANTONY: Bla blah blah**

You can see this is not the case as it's shown below:

```
line_1 = 'CASSIUS Brutus, I misunderstood your feelings, and therefore kept to myself certain thoughts I might have shared. Tell me, good Brutus, can you see your face?'

line_2 = 'Trumpets play. Everyone exits except BRUTUS and CASSIUS .'
```

The dialog is formatted thus:
The actor name is written **ALL IN CAPS at the beginning of the line**
For example

```
line_1 >>> CASSIUS
```

i.e. CASSIUS is the actor here.

However, some lines contain names of actors in the play (not at the beginning of the line) written in upper case format. See line_2.

What is required is a regex expression or a python methodology to insert a colon after every actor name.
We know the name of the actor by the following two conditions:

**1) It is at the beginning of the line.**

**2) It is written all in uppercase format.**

CASSIUS is the actor in line_1 (it meets both conditions).
However this is not the case for line_2 for BRUTUS and CASSIUS (they are in the middle of the line), hence not colon after their name.

---

Here is my attempt, which applies to the unwanted words BRUTUS and CASSIUS in line_2!

```
re.sub(r'(?<=([A-Z][A-Z]\b))', ': ', line_1)
re.sub(r'(?<=([A-Z][A-Z]\b))', ': ', line_1)
```

I get the following output, which is not good!

```
'CASSIUS:  Brutus, I misunderstood your feelings, and therefore kept to myself certain thoughts I might have shared. Tell me, good Brutus, can you see your face?'

'Trumpets play. Everyone exits except BRUTUS:  and CASSIUS:  .'
```

Comment: Why not use `re.sub("^([A-Z]{2,})", "\\1:", txt)`?

Comment: @DYZ; Thanks, it seems to work. I am new to python, hence I don't know much about capturing groups if that's what you did. Your solution seems to work well for my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is over-complicated. Simply replace two or more upper-case letters at the beginning (`"^"`) of a string. here, `"\\1"` is a reference to the first group in the parentheses.

```
re.sub("^([A-Z]{2,})", "\\1:", line_1)
# 'CASSIUS: Brutus,...'
```

Comment: No need for a capturing group, `re.sub("^[A-Z]{2,}", r"\g<0>:", line_1)` will do.